# Loading AdaBoostClassifier

Tags: scikit-learn, pickle, adaboost, joblib

```
classifier = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=100, learning_rate=1.0, algorithm='SAMME.R')
try:
    classifier = joblib.load("final_model_Ada1.pkl")
    print "using trained model"
except:
    print "building new model"
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
    joblib.dump(classifier, 'final_model_Ada1.pkl')
```

I wrote the above script for training an AdaBoostClassifier on some data.The pkl file is being formed the first time.But when I run the script again the model is being trained again and the previous model is not being picked up.I did the same thing for Linear SVC and that is working.Is there any other way to save an AdaBoostClassifier?

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting? Can you print that out?

Comment: There is no exception coming,a new model is being trained every time the script is run.

Comment: The fact that a new model is being trained every time means that your code is going in the `except` block. It goes in the `except` block because of an exception. Could you please print out that exception.

Comment: Did not recognise loaded array layout is the exception message